# goocanvas - coordinate systems and zooming to cursor

Tags: c, gtk, zooming, scale, mouse-cursor

I am trying to implement zoom towards the pointer/cursor within a `goocanvas` which is located within a `scrolledwindow`. Unfortunately the documentation about coordinate systems used is less than optimal.

So can anybody explain me why the following conceptual code should *not* work? (see inline code comments for details)

Convenience struct

```
 typedef struct {
     gdouble x;
     gdouble y;
 } Coords;
 typedef Sheet GooCanvas; // actually a subclass, but anyways
```

Just a convenience helper function (stripped tests)

```
gboolean sheet_get_adjustments (const Sheet *sheet, GtkAdjustment **hadj, GtkAdjustment **vadj)
{
GtkWidget *parent;
GtkScrolledWindow *scrolled;
parent = gtk_widget_get_parent (GTK_WIDGET (sheet));
scrolled = GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW (parent);
*hadj = gtk_scrolled_window_get_hadjustment (scrolled);
*vadj = gtk_scrolled_window_get_vadjustment (scrolled);
return TRUE;
}
```

Get the pointer position in pixel (verified, does work as expected)

```
gboolean sheet_get_pointer_pixel (Sheet *sheet, gdouble *x, gdouble *y)
{
GtkAdjustment    *hadj, *vadj;
gdouble           x1, y1;
gint              _x, _y;
GdkDeviceManager *device_manager;
GdkDevice        *device_pointer;
GdkRectangle      allocation;

device_manager = gdk_display_get_device_manager (
                gtk_widget_get_display (GTK_WIDGET (sheet)));
device_pointer = gdk_device_manager_get_client_pointer (device_manager);
gdk_window_get_device_position (gtk_widget_get_window (GTK_WIDGET (sheet)),
                                    device_pointer,
                                    &_x, &_y, NULL);

gtk_widget_get_allocation (GTK_WIDGET (sheet), &allocation);

_x -= allocation.x;
_y -= allocation.y;

x1 = (gdouble) _x;
y1 = (gdouble) _y;

if (!sheet_get_adjustments (sheet, &hadj, &vadj))
    return FALSE;

x1 += gtk_adjustment_get_value (hadj);
y1 += gtk_adjustment_get_value (vadj);

*x = x1;
*y = y1;
return TRUE;
}
```

For the actual zoom correction, we take the postion of the pointer in pixels, which is constant and independent of the goo canvas scale. Calculate the goocanvas positions based on the pointer position in pixels *before* and *after* applying the scale to the canvas. The difference is the offset between the position where the pointer is after zoom and where it should be (we desire a clamp to the canvas position). Get the top left corner of the canvas in canvas coordinates, apply the offset and scroll to the new top left position ([goo_canvas_scroll_to](http://developer.gnome.org/goocanvas/unstable/GooCanvas.html#goo-canvas-scroll-to) scrolls always towards the top left position)

```
void change_zoom(Sheet *sheet, gdouble f)
{
Coords a;
Coords pixel_pointer;
    Coords goo_pointer_before, goo_pointer_after;

GtkWidget *w;
GtkAdjustment *hadj, *vadj;

if (sheet_get_adjustments (sheet, &hadj, &vadj)) {
    a.x = gtk_adjustment_get_value (hadj);
    a.y = gtk_adjustment_get_value (vadj);
} else {
    a.x = a.y = 0.;
}

w = GTK_WIDGET (sheet);

//top left, not used, just to "visualize" the visible canvas range
Coords goo_tl = {a.x, a.y}; 
Coords pixel_tl = goo_tl;
goo_canvas_convert_to_pixels (GOO_CANVAS (sheet), &pixel_tl.x, &pixel_tl.y);
NG_DEBUG ("### top left [pixel]  %lf,%lf", pixel_tl.x, pixel_tl.y);


sheet_get_pointer_pixel (sheet, &pixel_pointer.x, &pixel_pointer.y);
goo_pointer_before = pixel_pointer;
goo_canvas_convert_from_pixels (GOO_CANVAS (sheet), &goo_pointer_before.x, &goo_pointer_before.y);
NG_DEBUG ("### pointer before scale[canvas] %lf,%lf", goo_pointer_before.x, goo_pointer_before.y);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
goo_canvas_set_scale (GOO_CANVAS (sheet), f * goo_canvas_get_scale (GOO_CANVAS (sheet)));
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
goo_pointer_after = pixel_pointer;
goo_canvas_convert_from_pixels (GOO_CANVAS (sheet), &goo_pointer_after.x, &goo_pointer_after.y);
NG_DEBUG ("### pointer after scale[canvas] %lf,%lf", goo_pointer_after.x, goo_pointer_after.y);

// this needs to be redone, as scaling might have changed the bar positions
if (sheet_get_adjustments (sheet, &hadj, &vadj)) {
    a.x = gtk_adjustment_get_value (hadj);
    a.y = gtk_adjustment_get_value (vadj);
} else {
    a.x = a.y = 0.;
}
Coords goo_tl2 = {a.x, a.y}; //top left, after scroll (in pixel coords)
goo_canvas_convert_from_pixels (GOO_CANVAS (sheet), &goo_tl2.x, &goo_tl2.y); // to goo canvas coords
NG_DEBUG ("### top left after zoom[canvas] %lf,%lf", goo_tl2.x, goo_tl2.y);

// the delta in goo canvas coords
const Coords goo_delta = {goo_pointer_before.x - goo_pointer_after.x, goo_pointer_before.y - goo_pointer_after.y};
NG_DEBUG ("### delta[canvas] %lf,%lf", goo_delta.x, goo_delta.y)

//apply the offset to the _current_ top left corner
goo_tl2.x -= goo_delta.x;
goo_tl2.y -= goo_delta.y;
goo_canvas_scroll_to (GOO_CANVAS (sheet), goo_tl2.x, goo_tl2.y);
NG_DEBUG ("### top left after scroll[canvas] %lf,%lf", goo_tl2.x, goo_tl2.y);

NG_DEBUG ("\n\n\n");
return;
}
```

**The issue is, although everything that is shown, the `goo_delta` *something* is wrong, the pointer is not fixed to the goo-coordinate. So my guess is, I need a secondary correction factor or I have a bug in the existing code.**

Example (`f=1.1`, cursor close to top left corner of the canvas)

```
 sheet_change_zoom +++ ### top left [pixel]  0.000000,0.000000
 sheet_change_zoom +++ ### pointer before scale[canvas] 7.000000,12.000000
 sheet_change_zoom +++ ### pointer after scale[canvas] 6.363636,10.909091
 sheet_change_zoom +++ ### top left after zoom[canvas] 42.045455,30.318182
 sheet_change_zoom +++ ### delta[canvas] 0.636364,1.090909
 sheet_change_zoom +++ ### top left after scroll[canvas] 41.409091,29.227273
 sheet_change_zoom +++ 



 sheet_change_zoom +++ ### top left [pixel]  50.105000,35.365000
 sheet_change_zoom +++ ### pointer before scale[canvas] 47.772727,40.136364
 sheet_change_zoom +++ ### pointer after scale[canvas] 43.429752,36.487603
 sheet_change_zoom +++ ### top left after zoom[canvas] 79.632231,56.789256
 sheet_change_zoom +++ ### delta[canvas] 4.342975,3.648760
 sheet_change_zoom +++ ### top left after scroll[canvas] 75.289256,53.140496
 sheet_change_zoom +++ 



 sheet_change_zoom +++ ### top left [pixel]  110.231000,77.803000
 sheet_change_zoom +++ ### pointer before scale[canvas] 81.074380,63.057851
 sheet_change_zoom +++ ### pointer after scale[canvas] 73.703982,57.325319
 sheet_change_zoom +++ ### top left after zoom[canvas] 110.037566,78.196844
 sheet_change_zoom +++ ### delta[canvas] 7.370398,5.732532
 sheet_change_zoom +++ ### top left after scroll[canvas] 102.667168,72.464313
 sheet_change_zoom +++
```

Any kind of tips, pointers to a goocanvas example which covers this specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it by looking into the goocanvas source and see how they did the actual scroll to center magic. According to that I moved the canvas pointer position to the center, scaled and moved it back. The important thing here is, that moving back is just the pixel position (here: just the diff in pixels between the pointer and the center when starting!) divided by the accumulated zoom factor! (use `goo_canvas_get_scale` to get it)

Note: The above description does not contain correction for clamping based issues.

Pseudocode:

```
delta = pointer_pos_in_pixel - center_pos_in_pixel
top_left_in_pixel read
top_left_in_pixel -= delta
convert_to_goo_coords (top_left_in_pixel → top_left_in_goo)
scroll_to (top_left_in_goo)

scale (f)

delta /= get_absolute_scale()
top_left_in_pixel read
top_left_in_pixel -= delta
convert_to_goo_coords (top_left_in_pixel → top_left_in_goo)
scroll_to (top_left_in_goo)
```

Note: to calculate the center of the widget in pixels, use `gtk_adjustment_get_page_size` instead of `gtk_widget_get_allocation`

---

**Addition:**

I implemented it for oregano, so for those that like real source code (GPLv2.0) see function `sheet_change_zoom` at https://github.com/drahnr/oregano/blob/master/src/sheet/sheet.c